# Use reactive expressions in renderPlot and download handler

Tags: r, render, shiny

I have had an issue by using the same reactive expression in `renderPlot()` and in `downloadHandler()`. I want to use the same reactive expression to minimize maintenance later. I have created two examples which create very simple figures (mwe1 creates a jpeg which you can download, mwe2 does not). I prefer a solution which uses a creative expression which can be both used by `renderPlot()` and `downloadHander()` as in mwe2. Is anybody able to help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

```
mwe1 <- function() {


app = list(
    ui = bootstrapPage(
        fluidPage(
            sidebarPanel(
                sliderInput("mean", "choose mean", -10, 10, 1),
                sliderInput("sd", "choose sd", 0, 5, 1)),
            mainPanel(
                plotOutput("hist"),
                downloadButton("histDownload")

                )
        )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {

        output$hist <- renderPlot(hist(rnorm(1000, input$mean, input$sd)))

        .hist <- reactive(hist(rnorm(1000, input$mean, input$sd)))

        output$histDownload <- downloadHandler(
            filename = function() {
                paste("hist.jpg")
            }, 
            content = function(file) {
                jpeg(file, quality = 100, width = 800, height = 800)
                .hist()
                dev.off()
            }
        )

    }

)
runApp(app)
}


mwe2 <- function() {


app = list(
    ui = bootstrapPage(
        fluidPage(
            sidebarPanel(
                sliderInput("mean", "choose mean", -10, 10, 1),
                sliderInput("sd", "choose sd", 0, 5, 1)),
            mainPanel(
                plotOutput("hist"),
                downloadButton("histDownload")

            )
        )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {

        output$hist <- renderPlot(.hist())

        .hist <- reactive(hist(rnorm(1000, input$mean, input$sd)))

        output$histDownload <- downloadHandler(
            filename = function() {
                paste("hist.jpg")
            }, 
            content = function(file) {
                jpeg(file, quality = 100, width = 800, height = 800)
                .hist()
                dev.off()
            }
        )

    }

)
runApp(app)
}
```

Comment: Both `mwe1()` and `mwe2()` appear to work for me.

Comment: Does `downloadHandler()` also create a jpeg which shows the plot as in the shiny application when you click on Download? For me it doesn't...

Comment: No the plot is blank in the second example.

Comment: Exactly. That's what I meant. Is there a way to create a non-blank plot by reusing the reactive expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `mwel2` to:

```
mwe2 <- function() {


  app = list(
    ui = bootstrapPage(
      fluidPage(
        sidebarPanel(
          sliderInput("mean", "choose mean", -10, 10, 1),
          sliderInput("sd", "choose sd", 0, 5, 1)),
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput("hist"),
          downloadButton("histDownload")

        )
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {


      output$hist <- renderPlot(.hist())

      .hist <- reactive(hist(rnorm(1000, input$mean, input$sd)))

      output$histDownload <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
          paste("hist.jpg")
        }, 
        content = function(file) {
          jpeg(file, quality = 100, width = 800, height = 800)
          plot(.hist())
          dev.off()
        }
      )

    }

  )
  runApp(app)
}
```

So call `plot` again on the `.hist` object.

Comment: Thanks! This behaves exactly as it should be.

Comment: Yes it was a problem of order. `renderPlot` was calling the reactive first and hence a second call to plot was needed for `downloadHandler'

Comment: But this doesn't work for function which were created by the user to create more complex plots, see edit.

Comment: @tnaake Please post as a new question.

Comment: The new issue moved to 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162675/use-reactive-expressions-in-renderplot-and-download-handler-when-using-own-funct