# Use reactive expressions in renderPlot and download handler when using own functions

Tags: r, render, shiny

[Use reactive expressions in renderPlot and download handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157990/use-reactive-expressions-in-renderplot-and-download-handler)

I have had problems by using reactive expressions both in `renderPlot()` and in `downloadHandler()` in shiny applications. I want to do this to reduce maintenance and redundancy in my code.

The above issue works with "normal" plot functions like plot, hist, etc. 
In my application I'm using a more complex function which creates a plot. I have created a simplified version of it

```
helpfunc <- function(mean, sd) {
    hist(rnorm(1000, mean, sd))
    lines(1:10)
}
```

If you use this function now in your `shiny app`, it does not work when creating a reactive expression out of it. Neither by using `plot()` nor by using the reactive expression itself.

```
mwe <- function() {
app = list(
    ui = bootstrapPage(
         fluidPage(
            sidebarPanel(
                 sliderInput("mean", "choose mean", -10, 10, 1),
                 sliderInput("sd", "choose sd", 0, 5, 1)),
            mainPanel(
                plotOutput("hist"),
                downloadButton("histDownload")
            )
        )
        ),
server = function(input, output) {

    output$hist <- renderPlot(.hist())

    .hist <- reactive(helpfunc(input$mean, input$sd))

    output$histDownload <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste("hist.jpg")
        }, 
        content = function(file) {
            jpeg(file, quality = 100, width = 800, height = 800)
            .hist() ## works not for plot(.hist()) either
            dev.off()
        }
    )

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lines` is basically a call to `plot.xy`. You have the same problem as you had before except this time you cannot assign the output of `lines`. As before you can assign the output of the `hist` function.

```
helpfunc <- function(mean, sd) {
  hist = hist(rnorm(1000, mean, sd))
  myLines = function(){lines(1:10)}
  myLines()
  list(hist = hist, lines = myLines)
}

mwe2 <- function() {


  app = list(
    ui = bootstrapPage(
      fluidPage(
        sidebarPanel(
          sliderInput("mean", "choose mean", -10, 10, 1),
          sliderInput("sd", "choose sd", 0, 5, 1)),
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput("hist"),
          downloadButton("histDownload")

        )
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {

      output$hist <- renderPlot(.hist())

      .hist <- reactive(helpfunc(input$mean, input$sd))

      output$histDownload <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
          paste("hist.jpg")
        }, 
        content = function(file) {
          myHist <- .hist()
          jpeg(file, quality = 100, width = 800, height = 800)
          plot(myHist$hist)
          myHist$lines()
          dev.off()
        }
      )

    }

  )
  runApp(app)
}
```